# Campaign Influence without Contact

Tags: campaign-member, campaign-influence

We have enabled Campaign Influence in our org, and it seems to be working correctly.  But looking at a Campaign Influence report, it appears that about 20% of Campaign Influences do not seem to have a Contact.

My understanding is that Campaign Influences are created when

1. a Lead which is a CampaignMember is converted to a Contact and an Opportunity, in which case the converted Lead becomes the Contact in the Campaign Influence record
2. a contact role which is a CampaignMember is added to an Opportunity, in which case the Contact becomes the Contact in the Campaign Influence record.

So how does our org have so many Campaign Influences without Contacts?

Comment: this is a good question for the salesforce Success forum where there are lots of sysad/power users

Comment: I thought it was campaign influence that was the junction object between opportunity and campaigns, as in no contact was required to link them via the primary campaign source field. I am correct that would explain your discrepancy (it's been a while since used campaigns).

Answer (score 0):

Campaign Influence is also created when Primary Campaign is set on the Opportunity. Those may not have an associated Contact.